# すごく to describe a person?

Tags: grammar

Can すごく be used to describe a person or only an inanimate thing?

Comment: Hmm?? Are you aware that すごく is the adverbial form of the i-adjective すごい?

Answer (score 7):

> すご**く** is only for adjectives and verbs

- すごく**あつい** - really hot
- すごく**つかれた** - really tired

> すご**い** is only for nouns

- すごい**人** - great/awesome/cool person
- すごい**山** - great/awesome/cool mountain

Comment: +1, but すごい can also modify an adjective/verb in speech. http://www.geocities.jp/sybrma/492keiyoushi.sugoikatsuyou.htm